# Html - Rowspan - Vertical spreading in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I have a table, where the left-most cell spans the entire height of the tbody via rowspan. The content of this cell can need more height than the rest of the table. I want the height of the rows to the right of the rowspanned cell to be evenly distributed over the height of the table.

In Firefox and IE it works as intended, but in Chrome I have whitespace above the topmost row:

[image: Difference between FF and Chrome]

As you can see in the grayed line, Chrome has unused whitespace above the gray line. This only happens when the left cell has content which needs more height than the combined height of the other cells.

Code of the table used:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">Multiline<br>text<br>longer<br>than<br>rows</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:gray">
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried cheating the renderer by setting the height of the first tr (which only contains the rowspanned cell) to 0px, but Chrome doesn't like a height of 0. It only reacts to the height definition, when it is at least set to 1px.

Question: Does anybody have an idea how to make Chrome behave like FF and IE?

P.S.: The idea of setting the rowspanned cell in its own line was a result of some other question here on SO by someone else in the past, which solved another problem I had back then. (By accident I didn't test this particular page in Chrome back then, so I don't have an exact memory now of which problem I solved with this back then. Sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Your rowspan cell and the top Bla cells should be in the same row. Then you only have 3 rows in the table so change to rowspan=3.

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Multiline<br>text<br>longer<br>than<br>rows<br>a<br>b</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
                <td>Bla</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```